# How to run Eloquent create() from child class on parent class using parent $table attribute?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, eloquent, attributes

I have the following classes

```
class Business extends Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'business';
     protected $fillable = [{stuff}];
}

class Employee extends Business {
     protected $table = 'employee';
     protected $fillable = [{stuff}];

     public function business_create(array $attributes = []) {
        parent::create($attributes);
     }
}
```

When I try to run business_create(), Eloquent tries to create a record on the 'employee' table.  How can I run create from the child on the parent class **and** use the parent attributes?